# Grid CSS Layout

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Я создал сетку с 6 блоками. Если я вписываю случайное количество текста в первый блок, он расширяется до размеров текста, но также все блоки в ряде тоже расширяются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.grid_body {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
   grid-column-gap: 17.5px;
   grid-auto-rows: minmax(400px, );
   grid-row-gap: 35px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   left: 17.5px;
}

.grid_item {
   width: 300px;
   background-color: white;
   border: 5px solid rgb( 5, 214, 73, 1 );
}

.grid_item img {
   margin: 10px;
}

.grid_item a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: black;
}

.grid_item a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}

.grid_item p {
   text-align: justify;
   margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_body">
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img1.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.
  iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequiptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.
  iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem seqptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.
  iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem seq </p></a>
 </div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img2.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.</p></a>
</div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti.</p></a>
</div>
<div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img1.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
</div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img2.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
</div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_item"><a href="#"><img src="../img/img3.jpg"></a><a href="#"><p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus? Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.</p></a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при вписывании текста в 1 блок, 2 других не повторяли его высоту ?

Comment: Верстку выложи, а не картинку....

Comment: Выложил, посмотри, пожалуйста.

Comment: .grid_body > div { height: max-content; } Может вы это имели ввиду. Но высота row все равно будет равна высоте самого большого блока. Может вы хотите ограничить по высоте блоки и добавить скролл?

Comment: Вы очевидно хотите получить masonry - на сегодняшний день на чистом css сделать это кроссбраузерно не получится, придётся использовать js. Но в перспективе такое будет возможно: https://habr.com/ru/post/526008/

Comment: Да, я уже понял, что mansory на js. Спасибо огромное за помощь!